# NSTableView will not compress

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, autolayout

I'm seeing kind of a weird bug with `NSTableView`/`NSOutlineView` and auto layout.

When I add an `NSOutlineView` to my nib and run the app, it will get bigger as expected from the given constraints, but it will never get smaller than the size it was in the nib. It's like it has an invisible "greater than or equal" constraint on it.

I have tested a few variations, and it seems that both `NSTableView` and `NSOutlineView` (inside the automatic scroll view) behave this way, but a plain scroll view with no content does not.

Comment: A screen capture of the `.xib` file from Xcode might be helpful, to show how your views are currently oriented.

Comment: Could it be that one or more of the `NSTableColumn`s in the `NSTableView` have a minimum size set on them?

Comment: @david-beck Did you ever figured out how to make it compress?

Answer (score 0):

[Please see the NSTableColumn documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSTableColumn_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which states

> minWidth
>   Returns the table column’s minimum width.
>   (CGFloat) minWidth
>   Return Value
>   The minimum width of the table column, in points. **The default value is 10.0.**

Comment: That doesn't answer the problem in the question, which is that the view “will never get smaller than the size it was in the nib”.